# MIPS Load Word Confusion

Tags: mips

Can someone tell me what the following means? 0($4) I know this can be rewritten as [0+$4]M

```
lw $6, 0($4)
```

I am not sure about 100($2) part, I know this can be rewritten as [100+$2]M

```
104: lw $1, 100($2)
```

I want to know what this means

Answer (score 0):

This is called **indexed addressing**.

```
lw $1, 100($2)
```

It means **"load word at address ($2+100) to $1"**

Memory address is stored in **$2**. 100 is the offset, from that address.

Comment: I have a question from this, what is the point of offsetting? My book and the internet seem to not have the answers Im looking for...

Comment: @Samuraisoulification With a memory area representing structured data (think structs), this is how you'll access a specific member. This is also how you can access a specific index in an array.

Comment: So its more or less for arrays and things like structs and classes?